# Cleaning the memory used by elements of linked list

Tags: java, list

I have a method that "removes" elements with odd indeces from the list:

```
public void deleting(List theList) {
        Link temp;
        Link current = first;
        int pos = 0;
        while (current != null) {
            if (pos % 2 != 0 && current != first && current != last) {
                current.next.prev = current.prev;
                current.prev.next = current.next;
            }
            if (pos % 2 != 0 && current == first) {
                current.next = current.next.next;
            }
            if (pos % 2 != 0 && current == last) {
                current.prev.next = null;
            }
            current = current.next;
            pos++;
        }

    }
```

So then I have to clear up the memory assigned to this elements. How can I do it? (I know that i need to use assigning null to elements but I don't know how to organize it to not have the `NullPointerException` going through the list)

Comment: Generally in Java you don't have to worry about "ghosted" objects or memory management in general. If an object has no references to it anywhere, it gets automatically removed by the garbage collector.

Comment: To expand on what @user1884155 is saying, you wouldn't assign null to elements, you would just reassign the current.next to skip the one you don't want. When there's no reference to the object the GC will remove it from the heap

Comment: What is ‘first’?

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is a reason to do this task e.g. dealing with flowing data. I suggest two solutions.

You can loop over List(java LinkedList):

```
public static void deleting(List theList) {
    List l = new LinkedList();
    for(int i = 0;i<theList.size();i++)
        if(i%2==1)
            l.add(theList.get(i));
    theList.clear();
    theList.addAll(l);
}
```

You can achieve this for example using stream also:

```
public static /*List<Integer>*/ void deleting2(List list) {
    List links = IntStream
      .range(0, list.size())
      .filter(i -> i % 2 == 1)
      .mapToObj(i -> list.get(i))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

    list.clear();
    list.addAll(links);
    //return links;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong for the second case when `current == first`.
It should just set next’s previous to null in that case.
That’s what causing the exception.

```
        if (pos % 2 != 0 && current == first) {
            current.next.prev = null;
        }
```

You don’t perform any memory cleanup in Java. The garbage collector does that for you.